# How to preserve order of insertion in SciPy Sparse Matrix COO_Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Hello SO python community,

I have a question about numpy sparse matrix COO format. It is as follows:

I have a `csv` file with 4 columns `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` and I need to form SciPy COO_Matrix from this csv file but I need to be able to preserve order of insertion of entries in SciPy Sparse Matrix. Currently, my data is ordered by column `d` and eventually in Matrix also I want this order to be preserved. Currently, this is what I do:

```
 def _build_interaction_matrix(rows, cols, data, score):

mat = sp.lil_matrix((rows, cols), dtype=np.int32)
for a, b, c, d in data:
     mat[a, b] = 1.0
return mat.tocoo()
```

Now when I call:

```
def get_triplets(mat):
    return mat.row, mat.col, np.random.randint(mat.shape[1], size=len(mat.row))
```

the order is lost and I have the order by `a` and then by `b`. Is there a way to order the matrix by key `d` so that I still return a COO Matrix with `a` and `b` as columns but ordered by `d`?

Edit: The final goal is to be able to *build matrix iteratively by preserving order and then convert it into `COO`*. I need to do it *iteratively* as there is a condition on column `c` which I need to check in the loop.

Edit2: I also need to implement `COO.getrow(row_index)` which preserves the original ordering of column indices of `row_index`
For the Edit2,

best I could come up with is this:

```
def get_all_items(uid, pid, u):
init = 0
indices = np.argsort(uid, kind='mergesort')

for i in range(len(indices)):
    if (uid[indices[i]] == u and init == 0):
        start = i
        init = 1
    if(i >= 1 and uid[indices[i-1]] ==u and uid[indices[i]] != u):
        end = i
        idex = indices[start:end]
        if len(idex) != 0:
            return pid[idex]
```

Thank you for your advice in solving this problem and if you need more information, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make a matrix in `coo` format directly, the order preserved, at least initially:

```
In [165]: row=np.array([0,1,3,5,2,0])
In [166]: col=np.array([1,0,3,0,1,4])
In [170]: M = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(6,int),(row,col)))
In [171]: M
Out[171]: 
<6x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [172]: print(M)
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (3, 3)    1
  (5, 0)    1
  (2, 1)    1
  (0, 4)    1
```

In fact the row and col attributes will be the input arrays (provided they are compatible):

```
In [173]: M.row
Out[173]: array([0, 1, 3, 5, 2, 0])
In [174]: id(M.row),id(row)
Out[174]: (2858024776, 2858024776)   # same id
```

But this order is easily lost.  For example a round trip through the `csr` format (used in most calculations) ends up sorting by row and then column

```
In [178]: print(M.tocsr().tocoo())
  (0, 1)    1
  (0, 4)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (2, 1)    1
  (3, 3)    1
  (5, 0)    1
```

And if there are duplicate points, they are summed

And for conversion to `lil`:

```
In [180]: M.tolil().rows
Out[180]: array([[1, 4], [0], [1], [3], [], [0]], dtype=object)
```

`rows` is by definition sorted by row, though within a row it doesn't have to be sort.

`sum_duplicates` performs lexical sort with column first

```
In [181]: M.sum_duplicates()
In [182]: print(M)
  (1, 0)    1
  (5, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (2, 1)    1
  (3, 3)    1
  (0, 4)    1
```

---

Building a `lil` iteratively does not retain any 'order' information:

```
In [213]: Ml = sparse.lil_matrix(M.shape,dtype=M.dtype)
In [214]: for r,c in zip(row,col):
     ...:     Ml[r,c]=1
     ...:     print(Ml.rows)
     ...:     
[[1] [] [] [] [] []]
[[1] [0] [] [] [] []]
[[1] [0] [] [3] [] []]
[[1] [0] [] [3] [] [0]]
[[1] [0] [1] [3] [] [0]]
[[1, 4] [0] [1] [3] [] [0]]
```

### getrow

`getrow` without sorting might be easier than I first thought:

Make a random matrix:

```
In [270]: M1=sparse.random(20,20,.2)
In [271]: M1
Out[271]: 
<20x20 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 80 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [273]: M1.row
Out[273]: 
array([10, 16,  2,  8,  5,  2, 15,  7,  7,  4, 16,  0, 14, 14, 12,  0, 13,
       16, 17, 12, 12, 12, 17, 15, 15, 18, 18,  0, 13, 13,  9, 10,  6, 10,
        2,  4,  9,  1, 11,  7,  3, 19, 12, 10, 13, 10,  3,  9, 10,  7, 18,
       18, 17, 12, 12,  2, 18,  3,  5,  8, 11, 15, 12,  3, 18,  8,  0, 13,
        6,  7,  6,  2,  9, 17, 14,  4,  5,  5,  6,  6], dtype=int32)
In [274]: M1.col
Out[274]: 
array([ 4, 15,  1, 10, 19, 19, 17,  2,  3, 18,  6,  1, 18,  9,  6,  9, 19,
        5, 15,  8, 13,  1, 13,  7,  1, 14,  3, 19,  2, 11,  6,  5, 17, 11,
       15,  9, 15,  7, 11, 15,  0, 16, 10, 10,  7, 19,  1, 19, 18,  9,  5,
        0,  5,  7,  4,  6, 15, 11,  0, 12, 14, 19,  3,  4, 10,  9, 13,  1,
        3, 13, 12, 18,  3,  9,  7,  7, 10,  8, 19,  0], dtype=int32)
```

The elements where row number is 10:

```
In [275]: M1.row==10
Out[275]: 
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       ....
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

The corresponding column values (they aren't sorted)

```
In [276]: M1.col[M1.row==10]
Out[276]: array([ 4,  5, 11, 10, 19, 18], dtype=int32)
```

Compare those with `getrow` which works with the csr format:

```
In [277]: M1.getrow(10)
Out[277]: 
<1x20 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [278]: M1.getrow(10).indices
Out[278]: array([19, 18, 11, 10,  5,  4], dtype=int32)
```

and via lil

```
In [280]: M1.tolil().rows[10]
Out[280]: [4, 5, 10, 11, 18, 19]
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me to understand the problem at least. Its building lil iteratively, in my code, which does not preserve the order. Is there are way around that? It seems `'coo_matrix' object does not support item assignment`. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Best I can think of is build the `coo` inputs in the desired order, but create the matrix itself once, at end.

Comment: I did that. Thanks. But faced another problem. COO.getrow(row_index) sorts non-zero column indices in descending order. Is there a way around to get actual ordering?

Comment: `coo` uses the base version of `getrow`, which uses the `csr` format.  I can add its code to my answer if needed.  `coo` also does not implement indexing.  You'll have to do your own sort/search of the rows and cols arrays.

Comment: Ok I edited question, If you can show an example, it can give me an idea as to how to proceed.

Comment: Why are you trying to use scipy sparse for this task?  Work with the `data` array directly.

Comment: Because my data is very sparse and it would be unnecessary overhead to work with dense arrays. Also,  I cannot change it because all the code until now is using `sparse` arrays and I will need to change lot of things.That being said, I need to be able to figure: given a sparse matrix `m` how to get column indices of a row in the order they were inserted.

Comment: Your latest edit: `M1.col[M1.row==row_index]` is very fast compared to my naive implementation.